# Trying to download mp3 file via API GET response using guzzle client in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, download, mp3, guzzle

I've tried several methods to download an mp3 file via API get request. I feel like as if I'm close but just can't seem to get the download.

My URL returns a binary mp3 file.

This is a portion of what I'm getting in my response header array returning with the get request. Hope this is helpful.

```
"Content-Disposition" => array:1 [
      0 => "attachment; filename=RE3e327a2615b93f528fee111da9b60e17.mp3; filename*=UTF-8''sample.mp3"
    ]
```

Here is a sample of my code using the Guzzle client in Laravel. Trying Laravel's download method but I believe I need to get the actual file from the Content-Disposition. Much appreciated for any help. Thanks.

```
    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $url = 'http://getmp3website.net/recording/sample.mp3';


        $response = $client->request('GET', $url,
         [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'bearer ' . env("AUTH_TOKEN"),
                'Content-Type' => 'audio/mp3',
            ],
        ]);

        return response()->download($response);

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return $ex;
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong? It wasn't clear

Comment: I can't get the file to download in the browser. I did add this piece of javascript but can't get it to work. Trying to paste the script.

Comment: `                console.log("data", response.data);

                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.mp3'); 
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();`

Comment: Are you trying to download the file via Ajax in the browser?

Comment: Yes, using axios. A post because I'm sending an id to a method to get the correct mp3. Posting my sample code.

Comment: // Get call recording
    proxy = id => {
        axios({
                url: 'calls/proxy/',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                responseType: 'blob', 
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log("data", response.data);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

Comment: Might not be very readable here in the comment section. Sorry.

Comment: You can edit the question to include that kind of thing. Anyway you need to focus your debugging a bit more. Check separately that the guzzle part downloads the data you expect. Then check the download from your controller without Ajax. Then finally add the Ajax back in. That way you can narrow down more specifically which area might be causing the problem.

Comment: Gotcha, OK. trying some debugging. Thanks.

Comment: _“but I believe I need to get the actual file from the Content-Disposition”_ - unless you need to extract the file name from there, I don’t see why what would be necessary. Can Laravel’s `download` method handle the full Guzzle response object, or do you maybe need to get the body content only using `$response->getBody()`?

Comment: I agree with @CBroe `response()->download($response);` would not download the body instead copy the contents to a file then use response download to download it you can delete it later

Answer (score 1):

#Note: this is not a tested answer, I have just provided an example to follow the comments above

```
<?php

    $client = new Client();

    try {
        $url = 'http://getmp3website.net/recording/sample.mp3';
        
        $resource = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::tryFopen('/path/to/file', 'w');
        //or you can use $myFile = fopen('/path/to/file', 'w') or die('not working');
        $stream = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor($resource);
        $client->request('GET', $url , [
                'save_to' => $stream,
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'bearer ' . env("AUTH_TOKEN"),
                    'Content-Type' => 'audio/mp3',
                ],
            ]
        );
        
        /**
         *  // As `save_to` is deprecated(guzzle wants us to download files as stream I guess), you can use sink as well, sink will automatically stream files for you
            $resource = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::tryFopen('/path/to/file', 'w');
            $client->request('GET', $url, ['sink' => $resource]);
        */

        return response()->download($pathsavedfile);

    } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
               // you can catch here 400 response errors and 500 response errors
               // You can either use logs here 
               $error['error'] = $e->getMessage();
               $error['request'] = $e->getRequest();
               if($e->hasResponse()){
                   if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '400'){
                       $error['response'] = $e->getResponse(); 
                   }
               }
               Log::info('Error occurred in request.', ['error' => $error]);
        }catch (Exception $ex) {
        return $ex;
    }
```